# number_format function of php and calculate with js

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using number_format function of PHP to format: 2100000 --> 2,100,000. Everything is OK
But when I using 2,100,000 to calcutate with javascript then I got a message: NaN.

So how can I solve this problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Because "2,100,000" isn't a number.... 2100000 was a number, but your formatting of it with `,` has made it a formatted string.... pass the raw number back to js, do any calculations with it as a number, and only then format it purely for display using js

Comment: That is because "2,100,000" is not a number. Its a string. Take out the commas for Js usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show the formatted number but echo the unformatted number elsewhere and use that in js. For example:

PHP

```
<div id="number" data-myvalue="<?=$number?>"><?=number_format($number)?></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var myvalue = $("#number").data("myvalue");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the commas from the number using a Regex

```
var myNumber = "2,100,000"; 

myNumber = parseInt(myNumber.replace(/\,/g,''), 10);

console.log(myNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

"2,100,000" is a string. You'll need to remove "," so that it can be parsed by JavaScript and used for calculations. It's better to pass numbers around without custom formatting. However, if you receive data in such format, you can deal with them like so:

```
var a = "2,100,000";
a = a.replace(/,/g, ""); //Replace all occurences of "," with ""
a = parseInt(a); //If you know it's an integer
a = parseFloat(a); //If it might be a float
a += 1;
alert(a); //Displays 2100001
```

Comment: it will alert "2101" since you only removed the first comma

Answer (score 1):

number_format returns 2,100,000 which is a string. 
If you want to make other calculations with that in js, you will have to convert it to a integer( or float depending on what you need)

```
var number_string = '2,100,000';
number_string = string.replace(/[^0-9]/gi, ''); // remove non-numeric charachters
var number = parseInt(number_string);  // parse the string to integer
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a split.join combination like this:

```
var numStr = "2,100,000";
var num = numStr.split(',').join('');
```